# How to display iPhone images (bmp V3 format) on QML in Windows

Tags: iphone, qml, bmp

I have a problem with iPhone images (bmp V3 format) when use Qt (version 5.6.0) to display them  on QML in Windows.
When I click file images directly, I can see it
But when I opened it by Qt, Qt displays a dialog error: Fail to read image.
I put an example bmp V3 format at below link

[https://files.fm/u/38c9b5ef#*=*](https://files.fm/u/38c9b5ef#_=_)

Comment: The reason is, that the format is not listed here: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.10/qtimageformats-index.html

Comment: Yes. I know it. So I asked this question to know if anyone still met this problem and what his solution is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just convert the image to PNG or some other supported format...

Check out this search result:

https://www.google.com/search?q=convert+BMP+v3+to+PNG

Comment: @mike: Yes I already thought about converting. But I am working with a devices on car (which use qnx os). So if the number of songs on iPhone is huge, maybe performance will be reduced. So besides converting, do you have any suggestion?

Comment: Sure.. why not try `QBitmap bmp("path/to/file.bmp");`  Can I see some of your code so I can get a better idea of what you've already tried.

Comment: You could use QWebEngine, download a web-based BMP v3 converter's source code, then put the code into the project and load it with the Web Engine, convert it there and then load the converted file, and hide the web engine.. the whole operation would be extremely fast.

Comment: Image {
        id: geri
        width: 300
        height: 300
        fillMode: Image.PreserveAspectFit
        source: "path/to/file.bmp"
    }

Comment: I found that root cause of this problem is Qt not support image format of Apple devices. So now I am trying to use imagemagick to convert them to standard format. Thank you for your support.